# Best way to go back and forth between two activities?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have two activities that each have their own listview and data.  At the top of each activity in the actionbar is a button to access the other set of data/listview.  I am trying to find out what is the correct way to go about swapping between the two.  If I always have it launch the opposing activity, the user could create an enormous backstack of activities so when they hit the back button it just keeps swapping back and forth, correct?  I am trying to prevent that.. just want to make sure I am using best practice to go about this.

Should I finish() each activity and launch the opposing one freshly each time the button is clicked?  Essentially, i want them to be able to freely swap back and forth without worrying about hitting back button a million times when they are done.

If any additional information is needed, please let me know!

Comment: or you could just let the user hit the back button when they want to go back to the previous activity like normal apps do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a ViewPager Swipper or a tabbed interface with fragments which allows them to stay in the same acitvity. You can even overwrite the back button so it changes to the previous tab when the button is pressed.

Or have 2 fragments that are swipped when the user presses the back button.

Comment: Each fragment needs its own activity though, correct?  That is how I currently have it... I think I understand where you are going with this, I guess I just need to better understand how to swap between fragments.  I will do some more digging for this.

Comment: No, both fragments would be tied to the parent activity.  Fragments can be attached and detached from activities dynamically.

Comment: I just figured it out and implemented that.. It works perfectly!  Not sure why I was trying to have each launch their own activity.

Comment: **"You can even overwrite the back button so it changes to the previous tab when the button is pressed."** : No, don't do this. If you implement a `ViewPager` within an `Activity` then changing between the pages should be done either by swiping or by using the `ActionBar` tabs. The `BACK` button can be used for popping the backstack for `Fragments` (if that model is implemented) but within an `Activity` it should always be used to either return to a previous `Activity` or to the home screen. What you've suggested could effectively lock a user into your `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TabHost` containing two `Tabs`, one tab per activity. On the click of `Tab`, launch the corresponding `Activity` via `Intent`.

See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using two fragments instead of two activities. In your case after clicking button just call 
`this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,new YourFragmentHere()).commit();`
 inside activity.

You can also consider using ViewPager with two tabs.